# Libreoffice Nested pie charts

Tags: libreoffice

In libreoffice I want to be able to do a pie chart similar to the one that image shows:

[image: Nested pie chart I want to display]

I tried to do it via providing 2 tables in my calc:

[image: Datasets]

For the "NO" answers from the right part I want to display the "nested"/"small"/"internal" pie with the data from the left.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: You might get better answers on https://ask.libreoffice.org. If you post the question there, please delete this one or post a link to the new one.

Comment: The feature was requested here: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50934
There is some recent work on it.